# JSONP cross domain request,but server return a json?

Tags: cross-domain

A Cross-domain request bothered me. I want to use ajax request jsonp data from a third-party data-bank. But some works, some not, maybe the callback jsonp-data is not supported, how can I fix it if the data-bank only return json?

```
function newcreateElement(url) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        async: false,
        url: url,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: "callback",
        jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
        success: function (json) {
            $("#div pre code").html(JSON.stringify(json));
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, readyState, status) {
            alert(textStatus);
            alert(XMLHttpRequest);
            alert(readyState);
            alert(status);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, can you please elaborate on some work and some don't... what did you observe?

Comment: hum..  I have applied five Cross-domain requests to five services  from one databank, two of them  i get the data i want,but others not,  pardon for my poor english!